# jsp query to insert employee id using another value

Tags: jsp

I am developing a claim management project from scratch. I am working on JSP + servlet + oracle 11g XE. 
While registering, the employee will fill the textbox with the name of the manager that he sends the claim to. When he enters the manager's name, the manager's id should automatically be inserted in the database under the column reports_to_manager.

Please suggest the query for the above operation.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for providing you with code, please try to solve this yourself and come to ask a question when you have a specific problem you have difficulty with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Manager table is like:

> Manager_ID | ManagerName

```
  Statement st=conn.createStatement();
  String Mname="value of textbox containing the Manager's name"

  String sql="select * from Manager where ManagerName='"+"Mname"+"'";
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
  Int ID=rs.getInt(1);
```

Now you get the required manager's id in ID and you can process on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  PreparedStatement ppst=con.prepareStatement("Insert into reports (Details)value(manager_id) ");
  ResultSet rs=ppst.executeQuery();
```